# kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property listener has not been initialized

Tags: kotlin, exception, listener

I created Callback listener between my two class. When i'm executing program i'm getting  `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property listener has not been initialized` this error

Here my code where i setListener

```
                        val process = Example()
                        process.setListener(object: CallBackListener{
                            override fun onMessageReveiced(msg: String) {
                                sendString = msg
                            }
                        })
```

Here my code where i initialize listener and set value to send

```
class Example{
   private lateinit var listener: CallBackListener
   fun setListener(listener : CallBackListener){
    this.listener = listener
   }

   fun doSomething(){
     ...///do somethin
     listener.onMessageReveiced(rMessage)
   }
}
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: Maybe because `doSomething()` is called before `setListener`. You should initialize listener variable before called. To be safe you can check initialized before called like 
`if(::listener.isInitialized) { 
    listener.onMessageReceived("...")
 }`

Comment: Which line is raising the exception?

Comment: @DCruz22 listener.onMessageReveiced(rMessage) this line

Comment: @ChampChayangkoon i don't think so because i'm calling setListener in beginning of function by the way i added safe but now not getting inside

Comment: Try setting the listener in the constructor, that way you're making sure the property is being initialized with the class.

Comment: Can you give example which constructor? @DCruz22

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the listener in the constructor, that way you're making sure the property is being initialized with the class. Example:

```
class Example(val listener: CallBackListener){
     fun doSomething(){
         ...///do somethin
         listener.onMessageReveiced(rMessage)
   }
}
```

Or if you want to keep the lateinit var and be able to update the listener later you can use init to initialize the property:

```
class Example(cbListener: CallBackListener){
   private lateinit var listener: CallBackListener

    init{
        this.listener = cbListener
    }

   fun setListener(listener : CallBackListener){
    this.listener = listener
   }

   fun doSomething(){
     ...///do somethin
     listener.onMessageReveiced(rMessage)
   }
}
```

In your implementation class:

```
                    val process = Example(object: CallBackListener{
                        override fun onMessageReveiced(msg: String){
                               //your code
                        }
                    })
```

Comment: But how can i give Interfaces as parameter?  And when i add as constuctor i need to also pass value on where i set listener...

Comment: @saulyasar I've updated my answer with the implementation code